# Как правильно установить cookie?

Tags: php, cookie

На странице **index.php** есть форма

```
<form action="/auth.php" method="post" data-action="auth">
<input type="text" name="login" class="login" placeholder="логин">
<input type="password" name="pass" class="login" placeholder="пароль">
<button type="submit" class="auth_btn">ВОЙТИ</button>
</form>
```

Отправляю ее с помощью `AJAX`

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on('submit', '[data-action="auth"]', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize()
          }).done(function (data) {
            $("#ooo").html(data);
          });
        });
      });
```

Далее идет файл **auth.php**

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$post = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = ? AND password = ?');
$post->execute(array($login,$password));
$game = $post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
if ($game){
    setcookie("usr", "hello");
}
else{
    echo "0";
}
```

Код работает, условия выполняются, но, кукы не устанавливаются, никак. Но если на странице **index.php** просто взять и установить их, то работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать параметр `path` со значением `/`.

`setcookie("usr", "hello", time()+3600, '/');`

Comment: Это я знаю как, спасибо, работает, не понимал в чем дело, ждите 8 минут)